# SSIS: XML to Excel export, truncation may happen due to inserting data from data flow column with a length of 4000 to database column with length 255

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, excel-2010

I'm using SQL 2008 R2 & Excel of format xlsx. I'm trying to export data to Excel through XML source.Everything is working fine, than for columns where data is more than 255 characters. I get a warning:

> truncation may happen due to inserting data from data flow column with
>   a length of 4000 to database column with length 255

I've tried changing registry and IMEX value as per the [blog](http://sqlblog.de/blog/2009/04/ssis-excel-import-column-data-types/). This doesn't seem to help me. Also, for me connection string (Excel Connection Manager) is

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Extract_8202014.xlsx;Extended
>   Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";

As per [MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms137643.aspx) for memo type columns we should define datatype as `longtext` if table is getting created at run time. I've done same. But it's not helping.

Comment: If just length not correct and there are no data with length more than 255 you can cut string in derived column with  substring function... after this new column length would be 255 or whatever you set

Comment: @Justin, Few rows of source has data which is more than 255 characters. Package fails as it encounters row which has data more than 255 characters.

Comment: it encounters error than destination column is too small for input columnn. So there are some solutions: 1. Make input column smaller (maybe split in two strings...) 2. Like you say yoo can try to change destination column data type.

Comment: splitting isn't possible. Also, changing datatype dynamically isn't helping. Package fails.